# UIImage Returning nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uicollectionview

I am passing data from one controller to another.

`TemplateController` which is the one that is sending the data looks like this:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     PreviewController *destViewController = [[PreviewController alloc]init];
     destViewController.passFrameLabel = [self.frameImages[indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     [self.collectionView deselectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
     [destViewController loadFrame];
     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

My `loadFrame` method in my `PreviewController` looks like this:

```
UIImageView *frameImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:frameImageView];
self.frameImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:self.passFrameLabel];
```

After debugging self.passFrameLabel contains the right value but `self.frameImageView.image` returns `nil`. What am I missing?

Comment: what is the value of `self.passFrameLabel` ? Are you sure that the image is in your bundle ? And the writing is correct (be careful to the case) ?

Comment: did you set the frame of frameImageView?

Comment: @KIDdAe Yes my image is in my bundle. The value of self.passFrameLable is the name of the file, a png file which actually displays correctly in its class(TemplateController)

Comment: @visualication what do you mean? frameImageView is declared as a UIImageView property(retain, nonatomic) in the header file.

Comment: is it displaye in simulator or not??

Comment: log the value of passFrameLabel and check it is really the name of your image (including extension)

Comment: frameImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,100,100);

Comment: @Edu is your image is in png or other extension? If It is other extension you need to give full name with extension.

Comment: @wasim it displays when I try to display in its class but when I try to pass it to the other controller it does not display.

Comment: @Bhumeshwerkatre yes I am providing the full name with extension and it is a png.

Comment: @slecorne the value of passFrameLabel is the correct including the extension

Comment: Is `self.passFrameLabel` a `UILabel` or `NSString`?

Comment: @Amar it is a NSString

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be creating `frameImageView` local object when your class also has `frameImageView` property. You are adding the local object of `UIImageView` as the subview but assigning `image` to the property (which is not initialised it seems).

You should modify your code,

```
//frameImageView should be a strong property
_frameImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init]; 
self.frameImageView.frame = CGRectMake(10,10,50,50); //Add suitable frame
//Now assign image
self.frameImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:self.passFrameLabel];
//Add this property as subview
[self.view addSubview:self.frameImageView];
```

Try it out.

Comment: @Amar, looks to be very close. self.frameImageView.view is nor returning an UIImage! But as I am using gesture recognizers, this gestureRecognizer is being called with "self.view" and the UIImage is not being displayed but looks now to be close.

Comment: @Edu Sorry but didn't quite understand what you are saying. Is your image view now getting displayed? If not can you log `self.passFrameLabel` and also try allocating and initialising `UIImage` with `initWithContentsOfFile:` rather than `imageNamed:` API.

Comment: @Amar It does not display. self.passFrameLable returns the full name of the png file and self.frameImageView.image returns UIImage.
If I use initWithContentsOfFile I get same thing. Everything logs correctly but the image does not display. I have another UIImage in the same view controller, might that be a problem?

Comment: @Edu Can you check if your `self.frameImageView` image view is getting hidden behind/overlapped another view? That could be the reason for not getting displayed.

Comment: @Amar I have another image view but I am placing both image views on different coordinates so that they don't overlap.

Comment: @Edu There seems to be some issue related to placement of the image view. Did set its frame correctly? Is it being added in correct superview?

Comment: @Amar yes. it has been set correctly. Have been trying to solve this for 4,5 hours :(

Comment: @Edu Sorry, but without complete code at hand its hard for me to say what is going wrong. I can only suggest.

Answer (score 0):

First things first - does the image of that filename exist within the project, and is it checked to be copied into that targets bundle?

Comment: yes. The image exists. Actually it displays in TemplateController.

Comment: Hmm in that case just check that self.passFrameLabel is returning your expected image name, apart from that I may be out of ideas :(